# Selecting values from a Pandas DataFrame with a hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a scatterplot of price vs. number for a certain year, say 2000.

I tried plotting with plt.plot(summary.price, summary.number, 'ro'), but I want it for a specific year so tried to only get the data from year 2000 with df['2000'] but it says key error.

How do I create a scatterplot with data from just a specific year?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the dataframe rows for index 2000 you can use:

```
df.xs(2000)
```

Other methods for selecting your data by the label of the index are:

```
df.loc[2000]   # label based
df.ix[2000]    # label and position based
```

[image]

Check [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) for more information

Comment: I reproduced your table and it works. Is 2000 a string or a number ? check that.